# Integrating Audience Network in Instant Articles

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network, facebook-instant-articles

I have integrated, according to the [Instant Articles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/ads-analytics) documentation, Audience Network ads, but I'm getting "HTTP error 503" as a server response.

This is the code that is implemented:

```
https://www.facebook.com/adnw_request?placement=PLACEMENT_ID&adtype=banner300x250
```

But my ad is not showing. Does anyone know why this is happening? 
Thank you.

Comment: Just double-checking, but did you replace `PLACEMENT_ID ` with a placement ID of your Audience Network app that has been created for the use with IA?

Comment: Yes. Here is the full link:
https://www.facebook.com/adnw_request?placement=1539502276355695_1539503109688945&adtype=banner300x250
Maybe it's just server maintaince.

Comment: Did you create that app from the IA Configuration section found at https://www.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/publishing_tools/?section=INSTANT_ARTICLES_SETTINGS - If not, that will be the issue. Instant Articles requires the app to be created from there to serve ads in IAs

Comment: I did follow the guide and created ads from IA Configuration section. Enabled Audience Network first and followed the instructions on creating ads.
Maybe a stupid question, but I just noticed that I need to create at least 10 articles to get them to be reviewed. Maybe when I create those articles and add the ad codes provided in AN, they approve it, maybe then I could see the ad that is being served by FB.
Any thoughts?
Thank you for helping with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bjorn is correct, the app id you're using is most likely a regular AN app id.  You would need to create an IA specific AN app id through the page you're trying to publish articles from through IA.  Here's a blog post that explains the procedure:  https://developers.facebook.com/ia/blog/post/2016/04/08/self-service-audience-network/

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I've mixed AN mobile web ads with IA placement id's for my page. Thank you for helping on this issue. Guiding me to the right direction.